# Execute a Select Query on another Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I need to Execute a SQL Query from my local Server on a SQL Server placed on Internet.

I can not use Replication because The Sever on the Internet is a Shared SQL Server and So I can on use those Methods like Replication, Linked Servers etc.

If I try to Create a Replication Service or a Linked Server, then the Following error is occurring

```
A required operation could not be completed. 
You must be a member of the sysadmin role to perform this operation. (SqlManagerUI)
```

I think the Select Query should contain the login Details for the Remote Server. How Can I include the User Details in Query??

Can you suggest me a method ??

Comment: Why not execute the query on the remote sql server itself.. ?

Comment: I'm creating a stored procedure in the local Server which has to get the data from the Remote Server and process it. So...

Answer (score 0):

Read about [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) and linked servers

Comment: why not? A linked server is just an entry in your database's settings profile. It is not like a "static" link that constantly exists in case of the server replications. When you add a linked sever to your database, it is like creating a connection string.

Comment: The Error Message is - `A required operation could not be completed.  You must be a member of the sysadmin role to perform this operation. (SqlManagerUI)`

Comment: If you're not the sysadmin on your local SQL server, can you ask the sysadmin to create the linked server for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) utility to connect to the remote server and then execute your query

```
sqlcmd -S IPAddress -U UserName -P Password
sqlcmd server_name[\instance_name] -U user_name -P password
```

Else u can give a thought about using `SSIS` package .to call your `stored procedures`

[Creating Data Load Package](http://www.petri.co.il/ssis-creating-data-load-package.htm)

Comment: Can we use `sqlcmd` in a stored procedure ??

Comment: I have never tried that inside SSMS .Check this article for more info http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/06/sql-server-interesting-observation-using-sqlcmd-from-ssms-query-editor/